# MacOS QGIS3.8.2, Opening QGIS prompts '....save the current project.'

Tags: qgis

When opening QGIS Zanzibar the following prompt message occurs. If the splash is marked on, in the settings, the prompt remains hidden but awaits for user prompt at startup.

Help to get rid of message.

This was not present in QGIS 3.4.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Sorry users, rookie question with rookie answer right in front of me.

It helps to untick the 'Prompt to save project and data source changes when required' so that it is not apparent on startup.

Found in 'Settings > Options > General > Template folder.'

[image]